# How can I convert the DateTimeField in Django from UTC to enduser's timezone (usually PST) when querying a Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-settings

I'm querying a Django model connected to a table in my Postgres database that contains a datetime stored in UTC.

My query code looks something like this:

```
query_set = table_object.objects.values()
```

One of the columns in the query set is the datetime value in UTC.

The model looks like this:

```
class ops_inbox_view(models.Model):
    requested_date = models.DateTimeField()
    other_item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    other_item2 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    other_item3 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    other_item4 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    other_item5 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    other_item6 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to convert this into PST or robustly in the enduser's local time zone. My current solution is to use pandas with `dt.tz_localize` and `dt.tz_convert` after loading the query set into a dataframe but I'm trying to find a solution that is easily manageable in one location of the project file structure of the app. In my settings.py, I have `TIME_ZONE` set to `'US/Pacific'` but because I'm using Pandas, the conversion to PST is not automatically done and will have to change many lines of code in my views.py to make the conversion with pandas.

Is there a way to not use Pandas and instead either make the field timezone aware or make the explicit conversion in the query code? Also looking for any other best practices in timezone management and display. Serving this datetimefield into an html file...

Comment: It isn't clear whether you want to convert to one specified time zone (e.g. `TIMEZONE`), or to "the enduser's local time zone", which can presumably vary on each request. Possible options include using a model property or method, or defining a custom model field which always returns a localized time.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Do you have an example on creating a model property or method or implementing this into the model field? I've seen a bunch of examples for using .now() but I'm not looking to have it populated with the local time this minute but looking to convert from UTC in the database to the local time zone.

Comment: Well I found documentation on writing a custom field

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score 2):

You can use F() with annotate

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F    
table_object.objects.annotate(modified_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('requested_date')+timedelta(minutes=960), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(modified_date='2019-11-30')
```

Here you need to +/- minutes to convert utc datetime to your(PST) timezone and it will store converted dates into modofied_date, after that we can filter it.

Note:

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pandas to convert timezones. Django good built-in timezone management tools.
Their [timezone docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) are quite good as well, so I'd suggest reading it all the way through.

The problem you're having seems very similar to [one described in their docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)

Comment: I've tried a lot of them especially with the template tags. Just trying to figure out how to use the timezone methods in line with the query code timezone.make_aware() since make_aware() doesn't take a series (would have to iterate over the returned  query set)

Comment: You will need to iterate over the queryset to render the data anyways. Use the built-in `date` [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date) to control how the date is rendered.